# Static Server Side Rendering or Dynamic Server Side Rendering

Tags: angular, typescript, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

To make a website SEO friendly we have to implement `Server side rendering` of the application in `Angular`.

I have read many of the articles on Server Side Rendering. While reading, I come to know about two types of rendering.

**1. Static Server Side Rendering
 2. Dynamic Server Side Rendering**

But What does it mean? I am not getting this from the articles I have read. Still confused which one to choose for my application.

So I just want to know for which type of application/website we have to use Static and for which type of application/website we have to use Dynamic Server Side rendering?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you say, there are two ways to render Angular apps on the server. Here is the difference, along with examples to illustrate their use.

#### Static Server Side Rendering

Essentially this refers to the process of generating pre-rendered pages for your app that you can then host statically using a service such as [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/). The fact that these files are static also means they'd be easy to serve out of a CDN. You simply build the files on your local machine or CI environment, then push to wherever your host is. Here's a short guide on [Pre-rendering Angular Applications](https://blog.strongbrew.io/prerendering-angular-apps/).

Ultimately each route you've defined in your Angular app results in an HTML file including any dynamically generated content that is displayed on load. This obviously plays well with search engines & crawlers. When a browser loads up one of your pages it gets an immediate pre-rendered response, then Angular kicks in with all the dynamic behaviour defined in your controllers, services etc.

**Example:**

You've built a marketing website showcasing some product. It has a fixed number of routes (home, about, contact). Upon building the app, you get 3 static HTML files, some Javascript, and whatever other assets are involved.

#### Dynamic Server Side Rendering

You may have guessed, this is particularly useful for when you have dynamic routes (e.g. `/products/:productId`). Using Angular Universal we can run an Express.js server in Node, which will dynamically render each page when requested by a client. This takes a little more time but is well worth it!

**Example:**

You've built a shop and every time you add a new product you want it to be available for Google and the likes to index. You also want it to display well in Open Graph preview renderers such as Facebook.

Comment: Does the `/products/:productId` route get re-rendered every time it's requested? Just wondering if there's a way to generate a static HTML page from a dynamic template and a method of invalidating it so that it's regenerated when the dynamic data driving it changes.

Comment: Hey @Mook5ter - yes, it would be regenerated on every request and could create a heavy load on the server at scale. I would recommend serving the app out of a CDN such as [Amazon CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) and setting `Cache-Control` headers during server side rendering. You can use Angular's `PLATFORM_ID` and `REQUEST` injection tokens for this, which will allow you to access the request object, similar to Express.js. Check out this tutorial on setting cookies during SSR as it uses similar logic: https://davidsekar.com/angular/set-cookie-in-angular-universal-during-ssr

Answer (score 7):

### Dynamic SSR (server-side rendering) & Static Pre-rendering

**Dynamic SSR** is the concept that there will be a live Node server spun up and whenever a Route is hit, it will dynamically generate and serialize the webpage and return that to the browser.

**Static Pre-rendering** is when we want to pre-render a list of routes, and create static files upfront, (ie: index.html, about-us.html, etc) and then use a **static file server** of our choosing (nginx, S3 hosting, etc) to serve up those files later on.

### So how do we know which one to choose and when?

Pre-rendering will typically give you better performance since we’re not waiting for a server to hit all the necessary APIs within your application, and nothing has to be “serialized”, it already has all the serialized HTML of your application outputted for each one of the Routes files.
Here’s a good list of questions that we consider with clients before considering which route we need to take.

### When to use Static Pre-Rendering:

- Your application itself is rather Static.
  (or at least the Routes you’re trying to pre-render)
  For example: homepage | about us | contact us
- Very dynamic portions of your site (and ones that are behind a Login/Auth barrier) can be pointed to the normal Client-side rendered (CSR) version of your application, and Angular can bootstrap itself normally.
- Your application doesn’t update very often.
  Whenever some changes are needed on the static routes, you can simply run the build script again and republish the /dist folder containing all of your pre-rendered files.

### When to use Dynamic SSR:

- Your application (and the routes you need to SSR) are very dynamic
- You have a list of “trending products” | “live data” | etc, that you need populated correctly for every server-side render.
- Your applications structure is rendered based on JSON files or a CMS where anything could change at any given moment.

**Typically most applications will need static pre-rendering**

Main purposes for SSR are SEO gains, and improved perceived performance. Any routes that need user authentication won’t gain much/any benefit from utilizing SSR.

Remember, you can always have certain aspects of your application not render during SSR, and have those dynamic portions populated during CSR! (client side rendering)

While you are at it, look at CDNs too. IMO, a few aspects of Pre-rendering and CDN usecases are similar.

Reference
https://medium.com/@MarkPieszak/angular-universal-server-side-rendering-deep-dive-dc442a6be7b7